# Preposition use: "at the gate," "among the crowded place"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> 1. He is standing **at** the gate.
> 2. He is standing **among** the crowded place.

If both are wrong what is the right usage?

Comment: 1 is OK, 2 seems strange.  He is standing among the people in a crowded place.

Comment: Sorry, due to semantic and grammar reasons, 'among' is unsuitable for expressing relationship in concrete space environment!

Comment: @Xavier: Often unsuitable, perhaps, but that's not always the case, (as in, "He is standing among the wreckage"). Depending on what just got demolished, that could be a _very_ "concrete" environment ;^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various dictionaries, for example [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/among), define *among* along the lines of

> in the middle of or surrounded by

This definition would lead one to believe that being in the midst of a crowd would endorse the sentence

> He was standing among the crowd.

However, virtually all of the examples in those dictionaries use a plural noun in describing *what* he is among. The term crowd is a collective noun but connotes the whole rather than the individual members.  *Standing among the crowd* just sounds wrong.

The phrase the OP offers

> the crowded place

is clearly a singular concept - a *place* that happens to be crowded. As such, it would not be an acceptable usage.

Answer (score 2):

First sentence is correct.  Second sentence should be "he is standing in the crowded place." Although even then it sounds like a sentence constructed by a foreigner. More common or natural would be "he is standing amongst the crowd"

Comment: Yes, you are right in saying that 'he is standing amongst the crowd' is more 'natural', but it must be specified that that is true only if 'crowd' is intended as an abstract noun! +1, anyway!

Comment: For love of preciseness: in my comment I meant abstract = uncountable!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández Abstract nouns are not all uncountable. Nor are concrete nouns all countable. *Crowd* is not an abstract noun, nor is it uncountable.