# Cards against (the?) humanity

Tags: articles, definite-articles

In the "cards against humanity" collocation, shouldn't the article *the* precede *humanity*, i.e. "cards against the humanity"? Does the word *against* somehow influence this situation?

Comment: Can you give an entire source sentence where you've seen this?

Comment: Sure, @Mitch. Whole collocation is a [product title](http://cardsagainsthumanity.com/) (no ad intended).

Comment: related:[Are there any simple rules for article usage (“a” vs “the” vs none)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none)

Comment: 'Cards _for_ humanity' works. 'I love people, it's humanity that I can't stand' works. 'Oh the humanity (of the Hindenburg crashing)' contrasts and works. 'Humanity' by itself is like 'Justice' or 'Friendship' or other vague non-specific concepts, that don't usually require an article 'Pain is a treatable condition', except when referred to as a specific instance like 'the pain of psoriasis'.

Comment: @MattЭллен:Sadly that question should make this one a dupe, but no one answered the 'none' option which is relevant here.

Comment: Adding to other comments, a parallelism item on an objective test might look like this: "crimes against humanity" ~ "crimes against the humanity" ~ 9,000,000 results ~ 40'000 results!

Comment: Exactly, @XavierVidalHernández: the name of the game is an allusion to 'crimes against humanity'.

Comment: Since when was *"cards against humanity"* a "collocation"? It looks to me like [something a marketing department dreamed up](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cards-Against-Humanity/dp/B004S8F7QM). As regards whether they could have included the word *"the"*, I suggest that's a matter for non-native speakers to ponder elsewhere. Here, it's just "General Reference".

Comment: @FumbeFingers ... but the question is primarily focused on issues in count and noncount nouns, and it is well known that some varieties of English (spoken by natives of that language)  permit countable uses of words which would be noncount nouns for others native-speaker varieties!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández: Can you elaborate on this well-known phenomenon? What native varieties of English do that, and what are some example words that differ from the standard?

Comment: @Mitch Yes! Varieties of English in Africa and Southeast Asia permit that, for example: 'Please put your luggages over there' (Malaysian English); 'Thank you for your advices' (Nigerian English)!  If you are interested in purchasing a book on this matter, I suggest you 'Interantional English Usage' by Loreto Todd, Ian F. Hancock. (Since I can imagine your objection, it is helpful to specify that Nigerian and Malaysian people are natives of English as second language!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a play on the expression "crimes against humanity" (itself apparently dating from the 1860 American National Republican Convention platform, describing slavery as such).

I think "humanity" is a mass noun here, and since there can only be one, the definite article feels superfluous.

Comment: _The_ is very commonly used in cases where “there can be only one”, such as superlatives: _the tallest building_, _the most likely outcome_. Or unique things or places: _the earth_, _the sky_, _the sun_, _the universe_.

Comment: I’m not really disagreeing with you on the substance, my point is that “mass noun”, meaning something uncountable, doesn’t sit well with saying there’s exactly “one” of something.

Answer (score 4):

In the question Matt linked to, [Reg Dwight wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2033/18696)

> Now, I can't think of a (= any) simple rule of thumb when not to use an (= any) article at all, but here are some suggestions:
>
> - Don't put an (= any) article before a (= any) noun if the (= that) noun is preceded by:
>
>   - a number
>   - a possessive adjective ("my", "his", "our"...)
>   - a "no", "some" or "any"
>   - a "this", "that", "these" or "those"

Add to that, don't use an article where the noun is a generality (or maybe, an uncountable noun, like *bread*).

"Cards Against Humanity" uses *Humanity* as meaning either "mankind" (human beings collectively), or "the state of being human", or "the quality of being humane". Actually, given the game, any of those definitions would fit. The cards are deliciously anti-social!

"Cards Against the Humanity" would raise the questions "Which humanity?" or "The humanity of what?" because you are talking about a **specific** humanity or type of humanity. As the "which?" or "of what?" questions either cannot be answered or are not relevant here, it's not appropriate to use the definite article.

Comment: "don't use an article where the noun is a generality" is a pretty strong assertion, almost unjustificable! Compare 'the/an answer' with 'the information'! As the example show, noncounts noun may be either concrete or abstract! Furthermore, some noncounts noun can be used as count nouns in special circumstance. While 'bread', as you say, is usually a noncount noun, supermarket assistans may speak of "all the bread in the bank", meaning the various types of bread (baguette, etc.)!

Comment: @Xavier: You're wrong. *Bread*, never *breads*; *information* generally or *the information* (specific data), but never *informations*. *Answer* is a concrete noun and so can take an article. And [**I've** already told **you**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78255/are-these-sentences-grammatically-correct/78257#comment153748_78257) that abstract/concrete does not correspond to uncountable/countable. And it's *unjustifiable* and *assistants*; and "all the bread in the bank" is hardly idiomatic, unless one is talking slang where *bread* may mean *money* (still uncountable).

Comment: _The_ is used with uncountable nouns like _bread_ all the time. _The bread is moldy._ Also with generalities.  _Where did the time go? / It’s for the common good. / The race is not to the swift… / You could cut the sarcasm with a knife._

Comment: @JasonOrendorff I'm not sure who your comment is aimed at (if anyone!) Of course uncountable/mass/general nouns can be made specific; just like *humanity/the humanity*. But where the intention is not specific, articles are not appropriate.

Comment: @Andrew, you’re coming across as really hostile. I made that comment because your answer says “don't use an article where the noun is a generality (or maybe, an uncountable noun, like bread)” and I think that’s unclear and can be improved. I don’t want to fight.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff My apologies; it wasn't my intention to be hostile towards you. Comments tend to be terse and open to that interpretation, which I must guard against. But I had considered (and, I think, still do) that my example of a "generality" immediately followed by an example of a "specific" demonstrating the difference was sufficient. I'm afraid I don't know why it's not.